# test vectors for IDEA

Tags: test-vectors, idea

I'm implementing IDEA algorithm in java and I need test vectors for the algorithm that include plaintext,ciphertext and keys in each step to verify my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one set of test vectors at the end of the [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=66E4D042AED44F429A447B16C5AF7BFE?doi=10.1.1.14.3451&rep=rep1&type=pdf) describing the standard; it includes round keys and the transformation of the plaintext to ciphertext for each round, but it doesn't zoom in on the values *within* the rounds.

Comment: NB: Bouncy Castle (Java crypto library) is pretty easy to understand / compile so you can use that or another library to print intermediate values yourself, using the test vectors in the paper as starting point. That would be implemented in `IDEAEngine.java` of course. Their test uses another test vector, without any comments or whatnot, so I don't know where they got that; I presume another library such as a PGP library (as that was where it was used the most).

Answer (score 0):

The values given in the IDEA paper (mentioned above) are kinda useless, they're decimal numbers representing internal states rather than { key, plaintext, ciphertext } triplets.  Here are some triplets from the original ETH reference implementation of IDEA:

```
K: 00 01 00 02 00 03 00 04 00 05 00 06 00 07 00 08
P: 00 00 00 01 00 02 00 03
C: 11 FB ED 2B 01 98 6D E5

K: 00 01 00 02 00 03 00 04 00 05 00 06 00 07 00 08
P: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08
C: 54 0E 5F EA 18 C2 F8 B1

K: 00 01 00 02 00 03 00 04 00 05 00 06 00 07 00 08
P: 00 19 32 4B 64 7D 96 AF
C: 9F 0A 0A B6 E1 0C ED 78

K: 00 01 00 02 00 03 00 04 00 05 00 06 00 07 00 08
P: F5 20 2D 5B 9C 67 1B 08
C: CF 18 FD 73 55 E2 C5 C5

K: 00 01 00 02 00 03 00 04 00 05 00 06 00 07 00 08
P: FA E6 D2 BE AA 96 82 6E
C: 85 DF 52 00 56 08 19 3D

K: 00 01 00 02 00 03 00 04 00 05 00 06 00 07 00 08
P: 0A 14 1E 28 32 3C 46 50
C: 2F 7D E7 50 21 2F B7 34

K: 00 01 00 02 00 03 00 04 00 05 00 06 00 07 00 08
P: 05 0A 0F 14 19 1E 23 28
C: 7B 73 14 92 5D E5 9C 09

K: 00 05 00 0A 00 0F 00 14 00 19 00 1E 00 23 00 28
P: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08
C: 3E C0 47 80 BE FF 6E 20

K: 3A 98 4E 20 00 19 5D B3 2E E5 01 C8 C4 7C EA 60
P: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08
C: 97 BC D8 20 07 80 DA 86

K: 00 64 00 C8 01 2C 01 90 01 F4 02 58 02 BC 03 20
P: 05 32 0A 64 14 C8 19 FA
C: 65 BE 87 E7 A2 53 8A ED

K: 9D 40 75 C1 03 BC 32 2A FB 03 E7 BE 6A B3 00 06
P: 08 08 08 08 08 08 08 08
C: F5 DB 1A C4 5E 5E F9 F9
```